# SharePoint Designer 2013 workflow start then cancel

Tags: 2013, workflow, designer-workflow

I installed the Workflow Manager on the same SharePoint 2016 farm.

I can create a  workflow that sometimes working, but sometimes gets canceled automatically!

Where can I check the work flow log?

Comment: Do you have access to the server where SharePoint is installed? If yes, go to SharePoint logs folder and you will find the error details of the workflow that gets canceled automatically.

Comment: Yes, I have! Is the SharePoint log  includ workflow manager logs! I can't get anything in sp logs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 places where you can find some more error information.

A. Retreive it from Database (not supported on production)

In the SharePoint page workstat.aspx, copy the field requestor id

1. In the URL query parameter from the worsktat.aspx page, copy the instanceid field
2. Open the WFInstanceManagementDB database with SQLManagement Studio,  then request from the DebugTrace table
3. The exception is in the WorkflowStatusDetail column

B. Server Logs

1. Start Event Viewer
2. Expand Applications and Services Logs \ Microsoft-Workflow
3. In the menu View \ Show Analytical and Debug logs
4. Select the Debug log, then right-click enable Log

more info on troubleshooting: 
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vincent_runge/2014/01/07/troubleshooting-actions-for-sharepoint-2013-workflows/